# What should I do when I notice that a question posted on ELU was posted on another site?

Tags: discussion

I am referring to this question [Where does the [sic] go in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331626/where-does-the-sic-go-in-this-sentence)  The OP mentioned he had posted it on https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/correcting-language-errors-in-quotes-from-official-sources/3726#3726.

This was obviously an innocent double-posting.  The question will probably be answered better here.

Comment: Standard practice is a gentle reminder to the OP that cross-posting is discouraged, followed by the closure of the question on the less-appropriate site (or sites). Note that if the questions are superficially similar, but *seek fundamentally different answers*, each suited to the site it is asked on, it's perfectly fine to leave them as-is.